# How to set language in django template by drop-down?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to set_lang from tuple in settings.py

```
LANGUAGES = (
('en', gettext('English'),),
('de', gettext('Germany'),),
('ru', gettext('Russian'),),
)
```

Urls've added

```
from django.views.i18n import set_language
url(r'^setlang/', set_language, name="setlang"),
```

Template has a part with lang_list and I'd like to set_language

```
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}

{% for language in languages %}
     <li role="presentation">
       <form action="{% url "setlang" %}" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <button role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" type="Submit" class="btn btn-link" id="login"
          value="{{ language.code }}" name="language">{{ language.code }}
                                    ({{ language.name_local }})
          </button>
       </form>
     </li>
{% endfor %}
```

It gives 404, and says that CSRF not found or not match.
"Reason given for failure:
    CSRF token missing or incorrect."

Comment: go to the generated source and check if `{% url "setlang" %}` is properly rendered

Comment: remove id from the button - you can;t have duplicate id's in html